# How to do a nested 2 level reshape in R?

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, reshape2, melt

I am currently working on a survey project that asks about respondents' economic activities. So we will ask the jobs/businesses they have, and since some jobs/businesses are seasonal, we ask about their revenue, cost, and profit in each season.

I am a bit stuck on how to reshape this in R from wide to long.
This is what I have:

| respondent_name | job_name_1 | seasonality_type_1 | job_name_2 | seasonality_type_2 | cst_1_1 | rev_1_1 | cst_1_2 | rev_1_2 | cst_2_1 | rev_2_1 | cst_2_2 | rev_2_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | farmer | high / low | teacher | active / inactive | 5000 | 6000 | 2000 | 3000 | 100 | 200 | 0 | 0 |
| Alice | livestock rearing | high / low | barber | active / inactive | 100000 | 200000 | 20000 | 30000 | 5000 | 7000 | 2000 | 0 |

I want the output to look like:

| respondent_name | job_number | job_name | season_number | season | cost | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | 1 | farmer | 1 | high | 5000 | 6000 |
| James | 1 | farmer | 2 | low | 2000 | 3000 |
| James | 2 | teacher | 1 | active | 100 | 200 |
| James | 2 | teacher | 2 | inactive | 0 | 0 |
| Alice | 1 | livestock rearing | 1 | high | 100000 | 200000 |
| Alice | 1 | livestock rearing | 2 | low | 2000 | 3000 |
| Alice | 2 | barber | 1 | active | 5000 | 7000 |
| Alice | 2 | barber | 2 | inactive | 2000 | 0 |

Anyone has idea how to do this? I used the melt function but can't figure out how to not lose the 2 level information. What melt gives me is just job_season_1, job_season_2, job_season_3, job_season_4, which lose the pair wise info between job and season.

Thanks so much!

Here is the toy dataset in the table above:

```
survey = data.frame(respondent_name = c("James", "Alice"),
                    job_name_1 = c("farmer", "livestock rearing"),
                    seasonality_type_1 = c("high / low", "high / low"), 
                    job_name_2 = c("teacher", "barber"),
                    seasonality_type_2 = c("active / inactive", "active / inactive"),
                    cst_1_1 = c(5000, 100000),
                    rev_1_1 = c(6000, 200000),
                    cst_1_2 = c(2000, 20000),
                    rev_1_2 = c(3000, 30000),
                    cst_2_1 = c(100, 5000),
                    rev_2_1 = c(200, 7000),
                    cst_2_2 = c(0, 2000),
                    rev_2_2 = c(0, 0)
                    )
```

Comment: Don't understand expected output. For example, there is no `300` value in the input data that would generate the `revenue = 300` value in row 2 of expected output.

Comment: Thank you! I just noticed the error that it should be 2000 and 3000 instead of 200 and 300, now corrected!

Answer (score 2):

first split the seasonality type1 and type2 into 2 columns and then `melt`, for melt i use the column numbers because your column names are too long

```r
library(data.table)
survey[, c("s1", "s2") := tstrsplit(seasonality_type_1, "/")]
survey[, c("s1_2", "s2_2") := tstrsplit(seasonality_type_2, "/")]
melt(survey, id.vars=1, measure.vars=list(c(2,2,4,4),c(14,15,16,17), c(6,8,10,12), c(7,9,11,13)))
```

Comment: This might benefit from changing from `"/"` to `" / "` (spaces, perhaps optional) or using `trimws`. Nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

This uses tidyverse and not data.table, but gets you most of the way there...

```
library(tidyverse)

survey2 <- survey %>%
  separate(seasonality_type_1, 
       sep = " / ", 
       into = c("season_1_1", "season_1_2")) %>%
  separate(seasonality_type_2,
       sep = " / ",
       into = c("season_2_1", "season_2_2")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("job_name"),
           names_to = "job_number",
           names_prefix = "job_name_",
           values_to = "job"
          )

  survey2_1 <- survey2 %>%
    select(respondent_name, job_number, job, ends_with("_1")) %>%
    mutate(
      season = 1,
      cost = ifelse(job_number == 1, cst_1_1, cst_2_1)
    )

  survey2_2 <- survey2 %>%
    select(respondent_name, job_number, job, ends_with("_2")) %>%
    mutate(
      season = 2,
      cost = ifelse(job_number == 1, cst_1_2, cst_2_2)
    )
```

What's still missing:

- Similar calculations for revenue as cost
- Removing unneeded columns, ending with similar column names in each of survey2_1 and survey2_2
- Joining (rbind) survey2_1 and survey2_2

Answer (score 0):

## The short answer

```
library(tidyverse)
seasonality_desc <- tribble(
  ~ job_number, ~ season_number, ~ season,
  1,            1,               "high",
  1,            2,               "low",
  2,            1,               "active",
  2,            2,               "inactive"
)
survey %>% 
  select(!contains("seasonality_type")) %>% 
  rename_with(
    ~ str_replace(.x, pattern = "^(cst|rev)_([0-9])_([0-9])$", 
                  replacement = "\\1_\\3_\\2"), 
    .cols = matches("^(cst|rev)_[0-9]_[0-9]$")
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    !respondent_name, names_to = c(".value", "job_number"), 
    names_pattern = "(.*)_([0-9]+)$", 
    names_transform = list(job_number = as.numeric)
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    matches("cst|rev"), names_to = c(".value", "season_number"),
    names_sep = "_", names_transform = list(season_number = as.numeric)
  ) %>% 
  left_join(seasonality_desc, by = c("job_number", "season_number")) %>% 
  select(
    respondent_name, job_number, job_name, season_number, season, cost = cst, 
    revenue = rev
  )
#> # A tibble: 8 × 7
#>   respondent_name job_number job_name       season_number season    cost revenue
#>   <chr>                <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 James                    1 farmer                     1 high       5e3    6000
#> 2 James                    1 farmer                     2 low        2e3    3000
#> 3 James                    2 teacher                    1 active     1e2     200
#> 4 James                    2 teacher                    2 inactive   0         0
#> 5 Alice                    1 livestock rea…             1 high       1e5  200000
#> 6 Alice                    1 livestock rea…             2 low        2e4   30000
#> 7 Alice                    2 barber                     1 active     5e3    7000
#> 8 Alice                    2 barber                     2 inactive   2e3       0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

## The long answer

We'll use two instances of **tidyr**'s `pivot_longer()` to lengthen the dataset, but there's some other wrangling that's needed in between.

### Remove metadata

First, `seasonality_type_1` and `seasonality_type_2` do not provide any individual-level information, but rather only metadata specifying the labels that correspond to the different season numbers in the context of the `job_number`. So, manually make a tibble containing these labels, and delete the metadata from the original dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

seasonality_desc <- tribble(
  ~ job_number, ~ season_number, ~ season,
  1,            1,               "high",
  1,            2,               "low",
  2,            1,               "active",
  2,            2,               "inactive"
)

survey2 <-  select(survey, !contains("seasonality_type"))
knitr::kable(survey2)
```

| respondent_name | job_name_1 | job_name_2 | cst_1_1 | rev_1_1 | cst_1_2 | rev_1_2 | cst_2_1 | rev_2_1 | cst_2_2 | rev_2_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | farmer | teacher | 5e+03 | 6e+03 | 2000 | 3000 | 100 | 200 | 0 | 0 |
| Alice | livestock rearing | barber | 1e+05 | 2e+05 | 20000 | 30000 | 5000 | 7000 | 2000 | 0 |

### First pivot: job number

The first pivot is by job name and number. Unfortunately, the job number appears in the middle of the `cst`/`rev` column names, and this doesn't play well with `pivot_longer()`. You can switch the job number with the season number manually, but if you're looking for an automated way of doing it, here is one way using regex:

```
survey3 <- rename_with(
  survey2,
  ~ str_replace(.x, pattern = "^(cst|rev)_([0-9])_([0-9])$", 
                replacement = "\\1_\\3_\\2"), 
  .cols = matches("^(cst|rev)_[0-9]_[0-9]$")
)
knitr::kable(survey3)
```

| respondent_name | job_name_1 | job_name_2 | cst_1_1 | rev_1_1 | cst_2_1 | rev_2_1 | cst_1_2 | rev_1_2 | cst_2_2 | rev_2_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | farmer | teacher | 5e+03 | 6e+03 | 2000 | 3000 | 100 | 200 | 0 | 0 |
| Alice | livestock rearing | barber | 1e+05 | 2e+05 | 20000 | 30000 | 5000 | 7000 | 2000 | 0 |

Now notice a pattern: all column names except `respondent_name` is of the form `<VARIABLE>_<JOB NUMBER>` -- exactly the specification we'll provide `pivot_longer()` (apologies, stack overflow is having a hard time rendering the markdown output for the table):

```
survey4 <- survey3 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    !respondent_name, names_to = c(".value", "job_number"), 
    names_pattern = "(.*)_([0-9]+)$", 
    names_transform = list(job_number = as.numeric)
  )
knitr::kable(survey4)

|respondent_name | job_number|job_name          | cst_1| rev_1| cst_2| rev_2|
|:---------------|----------:|:-----------------|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|
|James           |          1|farmer            | 5e+03| 6e+03|  2000|  3000|
|James           |          2|teacher           | 1e+02| 2e+02|     0|     0|
|Alice           |          1|livestock rearing | 1e+05| 2e+05| 20000| 30000|
|Alice           |          2|barber            | 5e+03| 7e+03|  2000|     0|
```

### Second pivot: season number

Now for the second pivot, notice that the `cst` and `rev` columns are of the form `<VARIABLE>_<SEASON NUMBER>` -- exactly the specification we'll provide `pivot_longer()`. This time, it's enough to just specify that an underscore is separating the names (we couldn't last time because there were more than one underscores present in the column names) (apologies again about the table):

```
survey5 <- survey4 %>%
  pivot_longer(
    matches("cst|rev"), names_to = c(".value", "season_number"),
    names_sep = "_", names_transform = list(season_number = as.numeric)
  )
knitr::kable(survey5)

|respondent_name | job_number|job_name          | season_number|   cst|   rev|
|:---------------|----------:|:-----------------|-------------:|-----:|-----:|
|James           |          1|farmer            |             1| 5e+03| 6e+03|
|James           |          1|farmer            |             2| 2e+03| 3e+03|
|James           |          2|teacher           |             1| 1e+02| 2e+02|
|James           |          2|teacher           |             2| 0e+00| 0e+00|
|Alice           |          1|livestock rearing |             1| 1e+05| 2e+05|
|Alice           |          1|livestock rearing |             2| 2e+04| 3e+04|
|Alice           |          2|barber            |             1| 5e+03| 7e+03|
|Alice           |          2|barber            |             2| 2e+03| 0e+00|
```

### Add in labels and clean

Now we can add in the labels stored in the metadata `seasonality_desc` we made earlier, reorder the columns as desired, and rename "cst" to "cost" and "rev" to "revenue":

```
survey6 <- survey5 %>% 
  left_join(seasonality_desc, by = c("job_number", "season_number")) %>% 
  select(
    respondent_name, job_number, job_name, season_number, season, cost = cst, 
    revenue = rev
  )
knitr::kable(survey6)
```

| respondent_name | job_number | job_name | season_number | season | cost | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | 1 | farmer | 1 | high | 5e+03 | 6e+03 |
| James | 1 | farmer | 2 | low | 2e+03 | 3e+03 |
| James | 2 | teacher | 1 | active | 1e+02 | 2e+02 |
| James | 2 | teacher | 2 | inactive | 0e+00 | 0e+00 |
| Alice | 1 | livestock rearing | 1 | high | 1e+05 | 2e+05 |
| Alice | 1 | livestock rearing | 2 | low | 2e+04 | 3e+04 |
| Alice | 2 | barber | 1 | active | 5e+03 | 7e+03 |
| Alice | 2 | barber | 2 | inactive | 2e+03 | 0e+00 |